# Начало изучения Java

Tags: java

*Здравствуйте.*

Мне *16 лет*. Изучаю языки программирования самостоятельно.

Сегодня проснулся, понял, что хочу изучить новый для себя язык, на уровне основ.

Начать я решил с **Java**. Хочу сразу изучать язык правильно, дабы в будущем меня не послали сюда **http://govnokod.ru/**.

**Вопрос:**

Не могли бы Вы, специалисты своего дела, подсказать хорошую литературу ну или видео-уроки. Это не умеет значения.

*Буду очень благодарен :)*

Comment: Поиск не работает что ли?
http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0+java&t=question

Comment: @a_gura, спрашиваю потому, что боюсь найти, что-то плохое.

Comment: @lamS пока в Виларибо боятся найти что-то плохое, в Вилабаджо уже все изучили

Comment: @a_gura, это конечно хорошо, но было время когда я был глуп, и нашел такого "хорошего" учителя как Евгения Попова. Я был уверен, что начав изучать по его урокам **php** смогу узнать очень много, но почитав литературу про данный язык программирования, я понял то что он меня обучил даже основой не можно назвать. После чего я стал просить помощи у специалистов.

Comment: вопрос оффтоп но тем не менее. просто интересно. этот вопрос был задан 8 лет назад. 8 лет назад вам было 16 и вы изучали Java. и как сейчас? кем вы работаете?

Comment: @midnightelf18 Был лидом 2 года в екомерсе, сейчас ушел на другую работку, пилю бэк на node и php :) А с джавкой иногда пользуюсь, веду разработку не большого мобильного приложени, все усилия в веб положил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал Joshua Bloch *Effective Java* (в русском переводе Джошуа Блох "Java. Эффективное программирование"). Легко гуглится.

Ещё хорошая книга Bruce Eckel *Thinking in Java* (бесплатная английская версия [на сайте автора](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/)), русский перевод Брюс Эккель "Философия Java" (у него, впрочем, есть аналогичная книга и по C++).

Comment: О, большое Вам спасибо, ждал именно такого ответа :)

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Если совсем основы интересуют, то можешь найти

> Файн Я. - Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, дедушек и бабушек - 2011

Кажется, там самое начало..

Comment: >для детей, родителей, дедушек и бабушек - 2011

Доставило название) Хорошо, тоже почитаю :) Спасибо.)

Comment: Там как раз самые начала даны - для старта вполне пойдет)

Answer (score 2):

Ну и [Хорстмана, Хорстмана](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3817476/) не забудьте )

Comment: Чем не ответ? :-) Преобразовал.

Answer (score 0):

Учи Java, но будь готов, что на нем пишут 90% под Web. Что касается книг, то если это твой не первый язык, как я понял, то достаточно ознакомиться с концептом с помощью Полного Справочиника. После того С++ или С идет на ура.